# Do not save changes to a datagridview if one cell is empty or null

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

Goodday I have the below code to save changes when i change rows. But something that 's important to me is to not save the changes if one cell "Discription column " is empty . How can i add to this code in order that i get a message box . 'Cannot save if discription is empty or a null'    thanks rob

```
     ' We need an indicator to know when we need to update the source database
Dim UpdatePending As Boolean = False


Private Sub ExampleBindingSource_ListChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs) _
    Handles ExampleBindingSource.ListChanged
' Whenever there is an update, note that a change is pending.
'
' ListChanged does not fire when moving within a row, so this will not
' mark updates until done with the row. (Here "done" could mean moving
' to another row or closing the form.)
If Me.ExampleDataSet.HasChanges Then
    Me.UpdatePending = True

End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowValidated(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.RowValidated
' The RowValidated event occurs after
' BindingSource_*Changed operations, which
' makes it a good place to update our source database.
' However, this event fires at a number
' of times when we don't have pending updates.
' That's why we need the UpdatePending indicator 
' to tell us whether to do anything.
' If we have an update pending, copy it to the source database
If UpdatePending Then
    Me.ExampleTableAdapter.Update(Me.ExampleDataSet.Example)
    Me.UpdatePending = False
End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event for RowValidating; do your test there, and if you fail, set e.Cancel to true.
So your code will look something like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowValidating(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e as System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.RowValidating

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value)) then
        e.Cancel = true
    end if

end sub
```

Comment: 'cancel' is not a member of 'systems.windows..forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs'